# Global ASP function

Tags: function, asp-classic, include, global.asa

I have an application programmed in classic asp. Now I need to create a new function that is accessible by all the files of my application, the problem is that I would have to add includes for all sites.

Does anyone know how to define this function globally without the need to add the includes?

I have already tried with global.asa but it did not work for me.

Thank you very much in advance.

a greeting

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to create an ASP function that can be called from any ASP file without including the function in the ASP page that needs to call it.

A common design pattern I use for a site (or a folder of related functionality within a site) is to create a file that contains this kind of thing -- global functions -- then include that file in every ASP file on the site/folder. One common thing this file might contain is a subroutine that emits the initial HTML before the content of the page, and another that emits everything that comes after the content. This allows me to easily give all pages a common appearance and (when combined with a common style sheet) to change that appearance without modifying each page. You can also include widely referenced functions in this file. For example, every page on my site has a login form at the top. The code to handle validating a customer's login credentials is in this global header file.